# How to use time.sleep() in miliseconds with a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the script sleep 462 miliseconds using `time.sleep()`, however nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
delay = int(462)
time.sleep(0. + delay)
```

The reason why I'm not doing `time.sleep(0.462)` is because I want to add user input later.

Comment: `print(0. + delay)` = `462.0` != `0.462`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input for `time.sleep` should be in seconds.

```
time.sleep(delay / 1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

it should works this way.

```
    import time
    
    delay = int(462)

    a = time.time()
    time.sleep(delay/1000)
    b = time.time()
    
    print(b-a) #shows the delay
```

I tried it. it works.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `delay` to milliseconds.

> 1 second = 1000 milliseconds

```
import time

delay = 462
time.sleep(delay/1000)
```

*`time.sleep(0. + 462)` will sleep for `462` seconds and not for `0.462` seconds as you thought because you are just adding two numbers there. `0. + 462 = 462.0`*

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the seconds with 1000 to get milliseconds:

```
import time
delay = 462
time.sleep(delay/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the delay with 1000

```
delay = int(input())
time.sleep(delay / 1000)
```